# Trouble Connecting to DYMO LabelWriter Wireless Printer on Android

Tags: java, android, printing, dymo

I have DYMO Wireless printer, and I have it set up to be on the static IP address of 10.0.3.7 and a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 (this is automatic and I'm not sure I can change it). I can easily add this printer to my PC manually by adding the IP 10.0.3.7 and selecting the DYMO LabelWriter Wireless driver. However, when I try connecting to this printer on my android device through Android's "Default Print Service," it says that there is no printer at the address 10.0.3.7. How can I properly set this printer up such that I can connect to it through my Android application?

I have no issue with the app's code, it seems, just connecting to the printer. This is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button print;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeWidgets();
    }

    public void initializeWidgets(){
        print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                print();
            }
        });
    }

    public void print(){
        PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(this);
        printHelper.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
        Bitmap image = getImage();
        if (image != null) {
            printHelper.printBitmap("PrintShop", image);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap image = null;
        if ((imageView.getDrawable()) != null) {
            image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the setup screen that DYMO provides:

[image: This is a screenshot of the setup screen that DYMO provides]

Comment: The default print service only supports Mopria printers. You may need a DYMO-specific print service

Comment: @Nonos Is there an easy way to find this? I am currently sifting through some code by DYMO in their mobile printing app, but I would gladly accept a shortcut if they have the source to a print service open for use.

Comment: Hello @Jacob 
Did you find any SDK or code to implement DYMO printer in owr android application ?

Comment: @UmeshAHIR No. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.